# BASH - run commands before and after loop

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, mount, samba

I'm having a bit of trouble with a shell script. It's something so stupid I'm almost ashamed to ask, but I can't figure it out.

This is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash

MAGAZINE="
    192.168.49.3
    192.168.49.5
"

SYNC="192.168.250.40"

#mount //$SYNC/PozeSync /home/alex/pozesync -o user=magazin,password=,sec=ntlm &&

for magazin in $MAGAZINE; do
    if ping -c 1 -t 1 $magazin &> /dev/null
        then
            echo "$magazin is down"
        else
            echo "$magazin is up"
            mount -t cifs //$magazin/PozeUpload /home/alex/mounts -o user=Administrator,password= &&
            rsync --bwlimit=1000 -r /home/alex/mounts/* &&
            rm -rf /home/alex/mounts/* &&
            umount /home/alex/mounts &&
            echo "$magazin done" >> sync.log
    fi
done

#umount /home/alex/pozesync
```

As you can see, there are two lines commented. If I uncomment them, the script stops working properly. It doesn't mount the pozesync folder and then throws some samba errors trying to load the folders in the loop.

If I run the mount/umount commands without the loop, it works fine. If I run the loop without the mount/umount commands, it works fine.

Run them together however and...

```
192.168.49.3 is up
rsync: link_stat "/home/alex/mounts/*" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: some files/attrs were not transferred (see previous errors) (code 23) at main.c(1165) [sender=3.1.1]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why put `&&` at the end of almost every line? There's nothing on the line afterwards to run if it's sucessful

Comment: Where does the `mount` command get the password from?

Comment: @Xen2050 thought it would be good to run the other commands only after the previous ones finish correctly. Thought that was a good way to do it.

Comment: @Paul I removed the passwords from the code, but they are supplied in the script.

Comment: I wasn't sure if putting `&&` at the end of a line would "chain" it to the next command, without being on the same line or a `\` or something to tie them together... but it does work as you expected/described. Interesting, +1 just for learning that

Comment: @Xen2050 yeah, I wanted the next commands to run only after the current command finishes. Otherwise it would try to delete files it's trying to copy, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

This was my mistake:

```
rsync --bwlimit=1000 -r /home/alex/mounts/* &&
```

should actually be

```
rsync --bwlimit=1000 -r /home/alex/mounts/ &&
```

Cheers!